# How to use buttons without intercepting the game controls?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I have a mobile game where the only thing you have to do is to tap to jump,now i added a pause menu and when i click it the player still jumps,after i click on resume button the player also jumps and makes the game annoying

How to fix?

Code:

```
 public void Pause()
{    
  Time.timeScale = 0;
  panel.SetActive(true);
         
    
}
public void Resume()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    panel.SetActive(false);
    
}
```

And for jump if u ask(it's called in void update):

```
 void Jump()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
    {
         rb.AddForce(Arrow.transform.right * -ImpulseForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the Pause and Resume Functions are activated by Buttons. Then you should probably look into Blocking Raycast on UI.

Comment: Is there a function for that or something?

Comment: couldn't you just set a flag `public static bool isPaused;` and then check `if(!SomeClass.isPaused && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) { ... }`?

Comment: still dosen't work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your setup, one easy way is to check if the current event is over an UI GameObject before adding the force to your rigidbody, using `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()`:

```
void Jump()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {
         rb.AddForce(Arrow.transform.right * -ImpulseForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Alternatives would be to use raycasts to check where a click went (UI or not) or implement one of the `IPointerClickHandler` / `IPointerDownHandler` interfaces.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked, i was trying to find a same ideea to check if the button is clicked but i didn't know of this, ty!

Comment: Found this one after a quick search. Let us know if it helps: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1115464/ispointerovergameobject-not-working-with-touch-inp.html